# How can I toggle all checkboxes with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code to toggle all checkboxes in a table which looks like:

```
const tblData = dummyData;
const [ allToggled, setAllToggled ] = useState(false);
const [ toggled, setToggled ] = useState(false);

const handleToggleAll = allToggled => {
    let selectAll = !allToggled;
    setAllToggled(selectAll);
    let toggledCopy = [];
    tblData.forEach(function (e, index) {
        toggledCopy.push(selectAll);
    });
    setToggled(toggledCopy);
}

const handleToggle = index => {

    let toggledCopy = toggled;
    setToggled[index] = toggled[index];
    if( toggledCopy[index] === false ){
        setAllToggled(false);
    }
}
```

and react-table part:

```
        Header: state => (
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={allToggled}
                onChange={() => handleToggleAll(allToggled)}
            />
        ),
        Cell: row => (
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={toggled[row.index]}
                /> 
       )
```

Everything works fine till I will use `handleToggleAll`. It will toggle all checkboxes to `true` state but then when I will uncheck `handleToggleAll` I'm not able to set them back to `true` neither any of single checkboxes can be checked back.

Comment: `setToggled` is a function and you're using it as an array `setToggled[index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats strange - i checked and toggle all is working perfectly well but ordinary toggle doesnt work and it can not as you dont call setToggled in your code...This should work well

```
const tblData = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const [ allToggled, setAllToggled ] = useState(false);
const [ toggled, setToggled ] = useState(
  Array.from(new Array(tblData.length), () => false)
);

const handleToggleAll = allToggled => {
  let selectAll = !allToggled;
  setAllToggled(selectAll);
  let toggledCopy = [];
  tblData.forEach(function (e, index) {
      toggledCopy.push(selectAll);
  });
  setToggled(toggledCopy);
}

const handleToggle = index => {
  let toggledCopy = [...toggled];
  toggledCopy[index] = !toggledCopy[index];
  setToggled(toggledCopy);
  if (toggledCopy.every(v => v)) {
    setAllToggled(true);
  } else if (allToggled) {
    setAllToggled(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great. I see where I have made mistakes.